# I need to convert a string to an integer within a hash

Tags: ruby

I have a nested hash and I need to return the inside hash, which is a value of the key. The problem is one of the values is a string and it needs to be returned as an integer.

```
def player_stats(player_name)
  game_hash.keys.each do |data|
    if game_hash[data][:players].keys.include?(player_name)
      return game_hash[data][:players][player_name]
    end
  end
end

game_hash = {
  :home => {team_name:"Brooklyn Nets", colors:["Black", "White"], 
  :players => {"Alan Anderson" => {:number => 0, :shoe => "16", 
  :points => 22, :rebounds => 12, :assists =>12, :steals => 3, 
  :blocks => 1, :slam_dunks => 1},
```

The code is correct, the only thing is that I need to input a line that will convert the string**(:shoe)** to an integer.

Comment: What do you mean by "inside hash"? There are several nested hashes. `game_hash` needs to be fixed. For one, it can't end with a comma. Also, there are 4 left parens but only 1 right paren. See my answer. Always test your code before posting.

Comment: I posted an answer to your question about converting the hash values to an integer, but I would like to point out a few unrelated things: 1) It is not necessary to do a check to see if a key exists in a hash; if you try to access a key that does not exist in a hash, it will return `nil`. If you want a different default value, you can use `#fetch`: `hash.fetch(:inexistent_key, {})`. 2) You don't need to use `return` as the last line executed in a block is implicitly returned. You would only use it if you want to return early from a block.

Answer (score 0):

```
game_hash = {
  :home => {:team_name =>"Brooklyn Nets",
            :colors => ["Black", "White"], 
            :players => {
              "Alan Anderson" => {
               :number => 0,
               :shoe => "16", 
               :points => 22,
              }
            }
           }
}
```

In this case, assuming you do not want to mutate (modify) the original hash, it's easiest to first make a *deep copy* of `game_hash`:

```
h = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(game_hash))
  #=> {:home=>{:team_name=>"Brooklyn Nets", :colors=>["Black", "White"],
  #    :players=>{"Alan Anderson"=>{:number=>0, :shoe=>"16", :points=>22}}}}
```

See [Marshall::load](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.2/Marshal.html#method-c-load) and [Marshall::dump](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.2/Marshal.html#method-c-dump).

Then just modify the value of interest:

```
h[:home][:players]["Alan Anderson"][:shoe] =
  h[:home][:players]["Alan Anderson"][:shoe].to_i
h #=> {:home=>{:team_name=>"Brooklyn Nets", :colors=>["Black", "White"],
  #    :players=>{"Alan Anderson"=>{:number=>0, :shoe=>16, :points=>22}}}}
```

Lastly, let's confirm the original hash was not mutated:

```
game_hash
  #=> {:home=>{:team_name=>"Brooklyn Nets", :colors=>["Black", "White"],
  #    :players=>{"Alan Anderson"=>{:number=>0, :shoe=>"16", :points=>22}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following your code, just a couple of changes (see inline comments in the option below).

Given the `game_hash`, which could have integers as string somewhere:

```
game_hash = {:home => { team_name:"Brooklyn Nets", colors:["Black", "White"],:players => {"Alan Anderson" => {:number => "0", :shoe => "16", :points => 22, :rebounds => 12, :assists =>12, :steals => 3, :blocks => 1, :slam_dunks => 1},"Reggie Evans" => {:number => "30",:shoe => "14",:points => 12, :rebounds => 12, :assists => 12, :steals => 12, :blocks => 12, :slam_dunks => 7}}}}
```

This is the option:

```
def player_stats(player_name, game_hash) # <-- pass game_hash as parameter
  game_hash.keys.each do |data|
    if game_hash[data][:players].keys.include?(player_name)
      return game_hash[data][:players][player_name].transform_values { |v| v.to_i } # <-- transform values to integer
    end
  end
end
```

Then, you can call:

```
player_stats("Reggie Evans", game_hash)
#=> {:number=>30, :shoe=>14, :points=>12, :rebounds=>12, :assists=>12, :steals=>12, :blocks=>12, :slam_dunks=>7}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few "issues" that I would like to point out in your `#player_stats` method, but I will focus on your problem with converting the player hash values to integers. To start off, I am making the following assumptions:

1. There is no consistency in whether the values are formatted as a string or integer.
2. All values are of integer form, in either the `Integer` type, or `String` type.

One thing I would like to point out is that shoe size could be `9.5` or `10.5`, etc. This could be the reason why the shoe value is formatted as a string. If this is the case, then you would need to take this into account and convert to a float using `#to_f` instead of `#to_i`. But since your question is asking for it to be an integer, I will use `#to_i` in my examples below.

Given my assumptions, you would simply loop over all the values in the player hash and call `#to_i` on the value to convert it to an integer. This can be done using the following method:

```
def convert_hash_values_to_int(hash)
  hash.each do |key, value|
    hash[key] = value.to_i
  end
end
```

You can call this method inside your `#player_stats` method. **Note that this method is mutating the original hash values in place without creating a new hash.** If this is not desirable, then you should use `#inject`:

```
def convert_hash_values_to_int(hash)
  hash.inject({}) do |result, (key, value)|
    result[key] = value.to_i
    result
  end
end
```

This creates a new hash with the transformed values, and returns it.

This can be simplified even further using `#each_with_object`, which also creates a new hash instead of mutating the original hash:

```
def convert_hash_values_to_int(hash)
  hash.each_with_object({}) do |(key, value), result|
    result[key] = value.to_i
  end
end
```

This approach does not require that you return `result` in each loop. Note that the arguments are switched for `#each_with_object` - `|(key, value), result|` instead of `|result, (key, value)|`.

There is one more approach that you could use which is the most succinct, **but it is only available in Ruby 2.4+**:

```
def convert_hash_values_to_int(hash)
  hash.transform_values do |value|
    value.to_i
  end
end
```

Which can be even more succinct:

```
def convert_hash_values_to_int(hash)
  hash.transform_values(&:to_i)
end
```

`#transform_values` does not mutate the original hash. If you would like to mutate the original hash, you would need to use a bang:

```
def convert_hash_values_to_int(hash)
  hash.transform_values!(&:to_i)
end
```